# What is a local base for a topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

On Rudin there's the following definition:

> A local base of a topological vector space $X$ is thus a collection
>   $B$ of neighborhoods of $0$ such that every neighborhood of $0$
>   contains a member of $B$

This definition makes no sense for me. For example, if we replace member of $B$ by 'neighborhood of $0$' then the above definition becomes:

> A local base of a topological vector space $X$ is thus a collection
>   $B$ of neighborhoods of $0$ such that every neighborhood of $0$
>   contains a neighborhood of $0$

Comment: I don't no if thats part of your confusion, but note that the notion of basis for a topology and basis of a vector space are very very different. You're dealing with the former.

Comment: Are you confused with the fact that not every collection of neighborhoods fulfills that condition? When you "translated" $B$ into words, you forgot to say that every neighborhood contains a neighborhood of $0$ belonging to one particular collection of neighborhoods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of neighbourhoods of $0$ such that if $O$ is any neighourhood of $0$ there exists some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B \subseteq O$.

A typical example in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{B} = \{(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}): n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$. These open intervals are all open neighbourhoods of $0$ and every neighbourhood $O$ of $0$ contains some ball of radius $r>0$ around $0$, so $(-r,r) \subseteq O$, and then finding $k$ with $\frac{1}{k} < r$, we see that we can take $(-\frac1k, \frac1k) \in \mathcal{B}$ and $(-\frac1k, \frac1k) \subseteq (-r,r) \subseteq O$.

The point is that sometimes we can take a small (here countable) set of neighbourhoods that are all we need for considering continuity at $0$, or closure properties of $0$, instead of the full set of neighbourhoods.

Comment: Doesn't every neighborhood contain neighborhoods inside? Can you give an example of a neighborhood around 0 that does not contain neighborhoods around 0?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs The point is that we can choose a **special** neighbourhood inside any neighbourhood; this collection of special ones is a base.

Comment: There's an $O$ that should be a $0$, right?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs yes, I corrected it.